# Parallel environment breaks fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, parallel

I have a chapter fully enclosed in the `parallel` environment. Placing the section title outside of the environment caused the creation of an empty page (with the section title only) and the translation starting from the next page. Placing the title inside the environment solved this issue:

```
...

\begin{Parallel}[p]{\textwidth}{\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\section{Translation} In the preceding chapter...
```

However this caused another problem: I'm using `fancyhdr` to place the title of the current (sub)section at the top of the page, but this particular section becomes invisible and is totally ignored, so regardless of the fact that my last section has begun, the last section title persists in the header.

I'm not sure if this is due to the fact that I'm misusing the `parallel` environment, but I'd like to know if there is a simple workaround.

Here is my MWE. Note that `parallel` is creating extra pages before it appears, but my issue with the header is still there.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, asymmetric,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document} 

\section{First title}
\lipsum[1]

\pagebreak
\section{Second title}
\lipsum[2]

\pagebreak%
\begin{Parallel}[p]{\textwidth}{\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\section{Translation} \lipsum[3-7]} 
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[3-7]}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume this is a `\global` problem -- something which is redefined by `fancyhdr` is stuck inside of the `Parallel` environment group.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What is `\global`?

Comment: @Alenanno: I meant something like `\gdef` actually.

Comment: If you place `\sectionmark{Translation}` explicitly into the last `Parallel` environment, it will appear (just for testing purposes)

Comment: The marks in a `parallel` environment are stored in `\splitfirstmark`, and `\splitbotmark`, rather than in `\firstmark` and `\botmark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `parallel` uses `\vsplit` for its working; the `\mark` commands issued by `\markright` (and `\markboth`) are then stored in `\splitfirstmark` and `\splitbotmark` rather than in `\firstmark` and friends.

If you just use `\rightmark` the following workaround *seems* to work, but it should be tested with a bigger document. I assume the section titles are in the left pages.

The idea is that, if a mark appears it will be stored in `\splitfirstmark`, so I test whether it's empty; if not, I issue an appropriate `\markright` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, asymmetric,headheight=14.5pt,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\ParallelParTwoPages}
  {\else\ifodd}
  {\extractfirstmark\else\ifodd}
  {}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extractfirstmark}{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\splitfirstmark}\relax
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\markright
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\splitfirstmark}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document} 

\section{First title}
\lipsum[1]

\pagebreak
\section{Second title}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\begin{Parallel}[p]{\textwidth}{\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\section{Translation} \lipsum[3-12]} 
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[3-12]}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working for the full document as well. I'll let you know in case I run into other issues that I cannot see now, but there doesn't seem to be any.